How to find a driveItem ID given only a document URL?
I need to be able to find a driveItem from the Microsoft Graph API, given only a document URL in this sort of format:
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/somesite/somefolder/somedocument.doc
I know it is possible to do the opposite, e.g. get a document URL from a driveItem, but how do I get the driveItem when I only have a document URL?

You can use Search API, filter driveItem entity type, and specify the document URL in the queryString
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query

{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "driveItem"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "path:\"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/somesite/somefolder/somedocument.doc\""
            }
        }
    ]
}

The response will contain resource property with inner id which is driveItemId you need. The parentReference property contains additional details like driveId
Another way is to get file by relative path, but it requires the knowledge of siteId and driveId related to the certain document library.
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drives/{driveId}/root:/somefolder/somedocument.doc:/


In 2024, the above worked without the path: prefix. with that prefix it returned 0 results on the v1.0 endpoint

For sample, I created folder in SharePoint site and uploaded document in the folder:

To fetch a drive Item ID given only a document URL via Microsoft Graph API, check the below:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/SiteID/drive/root/search(q='Document.docx')


To verify the same, I passed the Drive ID and Drive Item ID to check if it fetches the document:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/DriveID/items/DriveItemID


If you don't have Site ID, you can pass the name of the site to fetch the site ID:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=YourSiteName



This isn't a good solution for me, I don't have the site ID and this will find multiple documents if they have the same name but are under different subfolders

You can get the site id by the last query I posted in the answer

Glad to know that the other solution worked for you:)
